# ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'D:\a\1\b\2614'

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, directorysearcher

I am facing this issue while making CI pipeline in azure devops can any one please help in this

my yml file is

```
- task: ArchiveFiles@2 
  inputs: 
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId)'
    includeRootFolder: false 
    archiveType: 'zip' 
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip' 
    replaceExistingArchive: true 
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1 
  inputs: 
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)' 
    ArtifactName: 'drop' 
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

Comment: - task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId)'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'

Comment: What exactly is the relationship with C#?

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here:

```
rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId)'
```

There is no folder `$(Build.BinariesDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId)` on your build agent. Try to use

```
rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)'
```